# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript

```js
function sillyCipher(sentence, cipher) {
  let str = "";
  let keys = Object.keys(cipher);
  for (let key in cipher) {
    for (let i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
      if (sentence[i] == key) {
        str = sentence.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), cipher[key])
      }
    }
  }
  return str
}

console.log(sillyCipher("apple" , { a : "c", p : "x", l : "r", e : "o"}));
```

//i got SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat
could you help can't understand this error in the loop

Comment: Can you share what `cipher` is?

Comment: console.log(sillyCipher("apple" , { a : "c", p : "x", l : "r", e : "o"}))

Comment: `key` has a value of `?` at some stage, this is the problem

Comment: @Zhandos I made you a code-snippet, you might want to edit it to reproduce your problem

Comment: @Nick Parsons  ooo got it. Is it possible some how to add a backslash to the regexp variable?

Comment: yes, you add a ```\``` to key

Comment: You can, but you might find it easier to use `.replaceAll(key, cipher[key])` rather than worrying about escaping regular expressions